# How to display in a TextView the increase of size of my List

Tags: android, list

When I launch my Activity I put this piece of code:

```
     size = getSize();
     readRSSEvent(str);
     if(getSize()-size>0){
         events.setText(""+(getSize()-size));
     }

    public void readRSSEvent(final String s) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        url_ = new URL(s);
                        feed_ = RssReader.read(url_);
                        rssItems_ = feed_.getRssItems();
                        for (RssItem rssItem : rssItems_) {
                            item_ = new Item(rssItem.getTitle(), rssItem.getDescription(),
                                    rssItem.getPubDate());
                            list2.add(item_);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    size = list2.size();
                    SharedUtilities.getInstance().saveItem2(list2, getApplicationContext());
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }

public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }
```

But the code inside the IF never works because getSize-size always returns 0.
My goal was to look for feed and insert them in the List, save the list's size  and if the difference between my int size, and it was greater than 0 alert the user to the new event.
And repeat it every time I start the Application.

Comment: Use AsyncTask to achieve this ... because when you set the text view is set in sequential order but the Thread does't executes in sequence .

Comment: On create getSize() returns 0,size at start is 0,after readRSSEvent(str) size is 0 and getSize() is 14 then 14-0 = 14....or I'm wrong?

Comment: Try to use the answer I have posted ...in the function onPostExecute set the textView then check ... what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

It's considered bad practice to use threads in your [Android code](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html):

> [Threading] classes and methods also tend to make your code more complicated and more difficult to read. It becomes even worse when your implement complex operations that require frequent UI updates

Instead of a thread, you should use an AsyncTask:

```
    private class ReadRSSTask extends AsyncTask < URL, Integer, Integer > {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL...urls) {
        try {
            url_ = new URL(s);
            feed_ = RssReader.read(urls[0]);
            rssItems_ = feed_.getRssItems();
            for (RssItem rssItem: rssItems_) {
                item_ = new Item(rssItem.getTitle(), rssItem.getDescription(), rssItem.getPubDate());
                list2.add(item_);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { //Pokemon exception handling!!!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        size = list2.size();
        SharedUtilities.getInstance().saveItem2(list2, getApplicationContext());
        return size;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (result > 0) {
            events.setText(String.vaulueOf(result));
        }
    }
}
```

And you would call it with:

```
 new ReadRSSTask().execute(new URL(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it as.... new DownloadFilesTask(str).execute();

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Integer>{
String mURL;
public DownloadFilesTask(String url){
this.mURL = url;
}
     protected Integer doInBackground(Void... vo) {
                    url_ = new URL(mURL);
                    feed_ = RssReader.read(url_);
                    rssItems_ = feed_.getRssItems();
                    for (RssItem rssItem : rssItems_) {
                        item_ = new Item(rssItem.getTitle(),                rssItem.getDescription(),
                                rssItem.getPubDate());
                        list2.add(item_);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                size = list2.size();
     return size;
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer size) {
          if(getSize()-size>0){
     events.setText(""+(getSize()-size));
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: I get this error DownloadFilesTask() in DownloadFilesTask cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: this is because constructor was private ... i accidentally wrote void rather then public .... because I write this code for you in **NotePad** :p